# Problem in retrieving data from different tables in laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I am retrieving data from 3 tables account, product and stock. Account and product has one to many relation and product and stock has one to many relation, I am trying to retrieve data using account table, here is my query:

```
$account=Account::find(1);
$result=$account->product->stock;
echo($result);
```

I am getting result but problem is that I need some specific columns from stock table and when I write following code I am getting error property does not exist:

```
$result=$account->product->stock->model;
```

Comment: Can you Post your Relation Code on Product model. I think stock returns Collection, not single result.

Comment: ``` function stock(){ return $this->hasMany(Stock::class);}

Comment: I think its error in array's index when i echo it

Answer (score 0):

//in controller first get account data

```
$account=Account::find(1);
$products=$account->product;
foreach($products as $product){
$productData=$product->stock;
}
//in account model
use App\Product;//model name
function product(){
  return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'account_id');
}
//in product model
use App\Stock //model name
function stock(){
  return $this->hasMany(Stock::class, 'product_id');
}
```

Comment: I have done all this and  and i am getting all data but when i try to retrieve specific columns then it gives error